# onclick event working on index.html, but not on main.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, openlayers

I have an onclick event in my index.html file as below:

```
<a onclick="startDraw('Point')" class="card-link" >Add Point</a>
```

It is only working on index.html file if I use

```
<script>
  function startDraw(point) {
    console.log(point)
  }
</script>
```

tag.

However if trying to define it in main.js file it shows following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: startDraw is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):59:56)

Comment: Then you most likely have not included the reference to the main.js file. Also, if that's the content of the main.js file, remove the `<script>` tags. *.js files should only contain JS, not HTML.

Comment: Or it's *scoped* in your main.js - `onclick=` functions must be *global*.

Comment: On a related note, remove the `onclick` attribute and use unobtrusive event handlers. `onX` attributes are outdated and not good practive.

Comment: Do you have a `<script src='main.js'></script>` in your index.html?   Add `alert("main.js")` to the top of your main.js to ensure it's being included.   Maybe your `src=` has the wrong path?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Showing us the `<script>` that *works* isn't as useful as showing us the one you are having a problem with.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is no <script> tag in main.js. If I have it in main then I get error related to tag not function

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also onclick is working fine if I use script tag in html file.

Comment: @freedomn-m It is included correctly like <script src='.main.js'></script> As it is node js auto generated. Created using create command.

Comment: `src='.main.js'` is *not* correct - either typo in question or not working.  Do you get the test alert?

Comment: @freedomn-m It is like                                                                                                 <script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>                                                                         Auto generated, please see below link clearly written:                                                npm create ol-app my-app                                                                                                           https://openlayers.org/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will see unobtrusive event handlers, and update soon.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for help. It is done with unobtrusive event handlers.

Comment: Would be interesting to see your main.js.   Sounds like `function startDraw` is in an IIFE / doc.ready or other scope.  Or there are syntax errors in your main.js so it doesn't load.

Comment: @freedomn-m My Main.js is here now https://jsfiddle.net/himanshuactive/az14tkp3/

Comment: So, to be clear, your main.js is (now?) nothing like your `<script>`?  Or is that the *updated* main.js as it looks like your answer below.  Above, I did mean, it would be interesting to see your original main.js.   Just out of interest to see what the issue actually was.   Glad you got it sorted though.

Comment: @freedomn-m It was almost same Just function startDraw(point) {
    console.log(point)
  } is replaced with var startDraw = document.getElementsByClassName("card-link");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using unobtrusive event handlers, it worked.
Thank you @RoryMcCrossan

I just converted

```
function startDraw(point) {
    console.log(point)
  }
```

To something like this

```
var startDraw = document.getElementsByClassName("card-link");

    for (var i = 0; i < startDraw.length; i++)
    {
      startDraw[i].addEventListener('click', function () {                        
        {           
          alert(this.getAttribute('data'));             
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Although I'd suggest using `addEventListener()` instead of `onclick`

Comment: Right @RoryMcCrossan, will update to addEventListener()